# Cordova plugin PictureInPicture for ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am finding any cordova plugin to PictureInPicture for IOS. There is one plugin only for PictureInPicture which is only developed for android and working fine but I need one for ios as well.

For android I have used the plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-pip.

Please let me know if there is any plugin available or how I can achieve this.

Comment: How are you playing Videos??  you can use videojs to use picture in picture mode: https://github.com/collab-project/videojs-record/blob/master/examples/picture-in-picture.html

Comment: I am not playing videos I am using google maps inside the application and I want whenever the application gets minimize then the PictureInPicture mode should be enable for application.